# users drop marker and get link that will open the map there

Tags: google-maps-api-3, hyperlink, maps, marker

I'd like my users to be able to drop a marker on my map and be able to get a url link which will go to my website and open the map and show the marker.

So I think I need 3 things really

1. How to enable users to drop a marker
2. Get its link as a URL
3. Enable the link to open the site's map and show the marker.

Are there any examples out there that will be of help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two that are relevant:

- [Random marker placement along with sidebar creation and hyperlink](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sidebar/random-markers.html)
- [Draggable markers with geolocation](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html)

Comment: Thanks Tony - that gives me something to work from. And I have figured out how to do the url thing.